Keep double quotes in R read_csv to read JSON data
I have a csv file imported from a sql database, one of the column is made of JSON data. I used to be able to read_csv the file and then parse the JSON data using fromJSON.
However, now when I read the file the double quotations marks around the JSON fields are automatically removed and I can't find a way to prevent that from happening.
Here is an example. CSV file looks like this (3 columns, 4 rows):
A,B,C
1,2,"[{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]"
3,4,"[{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]"
5,6,"[{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]"
7,8,"[{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]"

json_data<-read_csv(file="test.csv") produces
> json_data
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  A     B C                       
 <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                   
  1     2 [{C1:C6.bmp,C2: C5.bmp}]
  3     4 [{C1:C6.bmp,C2: C5.bmp}]
  5     6 [{C1:C6.bmp,C2: C5.bmp}]
  7     8 [{C1:C6.bmp,C2: C5.bmp}]

instead of the expected:
> json_data
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  A     B C                       
 <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                   
  1     2 [{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]
  3     4 [{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]
  5     6 [{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]
  7     8 [{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]

Without quotation marks column C cannot be passed on to fromJSON...

That’s a bit of an impossible request: your CSV data is simply ill-formed, and whatever is producing the file is doing so incorrectly. However, you could instruct read_csv to ignore quotation marks entirely (by passing quote=''), and then manually remove just the outer quotation marks from the third column using e.g. sub() after reading the file.

Thanks for your comment but the csv file is well formed, it's a direct export from mysql DB, each column is one consistent data field separated by a comma. The problem is that read_csv is removing double quotes within strings, why would it do that? and apparently there is no way of controlling it...

(a) No, the file is not well-formed. It’s broken. Admittedly here are several conventions for CSV files, but the example you’ve posted violates all of them, and makes it impossible to reliably parse the file. If you don’t believe me, consider what happens if a value contains a quote immediately followed by a comma. How would the parser know that this was part of the value, rather than the field separator? In general, it can’t. You might want to check the MySQL documentation to see if you can tell it to escape quotes inside values.

(b) read_csv is making valid, well-documented assumptions about the format of the CSV file. That’s why it’s removing quotes: because most users expect it to. But, contrary to what you’ve said, you can control this, and my initial comment told you how.

If you can control how that file is created, you could get it to use single quotes around the JSON strings, i.e.
A,B,C
1,2,'[{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]'
3,4,'[{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]'
5,6,'[{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]'
7,8,'[{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]'

and then read.csv or read_csv will read it properly as long as you specify quote = "'":
> read.csv("~/temp/test.csv", quote="'")
  A B                                C
1 1 2 [{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]
2 3 4 [{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]
3 5 6 [{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]
4 7 8 [{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]

If you can't control that, you might be able to edit the file to look like that; in your sample, the only place "[ appears is at the start of the JSON, and the only place ]" appears is at the end.  If this is also true for your real data, then you could make that edit pretty easily.
If that's not feasible, then you could read it with quote = "", which will leave all the quotes in place.  The trouble with this is that the comma in the JSON will be taken to be a column separator, so you'll have a lot of fixups to do afterwards.

Using readLines(), then gsub commas between word characters to something e.g. an asterisk and strsplit at it.
> s <- gsub(readLines("foo.csv"), pat="(?<=\\w),", rep="*", perl=TRUE) |> 
+   strsplit('\\*')
> do.call('rbind.data.frame', s[-1]) |> setNames(s[[1]])
  A B                                  C
1 1 2 "[{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]"
2 3 4 "[{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]"
3 5 6 "[{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]"
4 7 8 "[{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]"


1) sub Read in the csv file, replace the first and last double quote with single quotes and then read in the file specifying single quote as the quote character.  Single quote can be replaced with any character that does not occur in the file.
"test.csv" |>
  readLines() |>
  sub('"(.*)"', "'\\1'", x = _) |>
  read.csv(text = _, quote = "'")
##   A B                                C
## 1 1 2 [{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]
## 2 3 4 [{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]
## 3 5 6 [{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]
## 4 7 8 [{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]

2) sed Alternately we could preprocess the file outside of R using sed and pipe that to read.csv.
Below we have assumed

Windows cmd line escaping
sed, which comes with Rtools, is on your Windows PATH
the first double quote is to be replaced with @
the double quote at the end of the line is to be replaced with @.

We used @ instead single quote to avoid some problems with its interpretation on the cmd line.  Any character not in the file will do as long as it does not have a special interpretation by the cmd line processor.
If using Linux sed is included but the escaping may need to be modified slightly.
read.csv(pipe('sed -e "s/\\"/@/" -e "s/\\"$/@/" test.csv'), quote = "@")

3) read.fwf This only works if the fields are in the same positions in every line.  This is the case in the question's example.
read.fwf("test.csv", c(1, 1, 1, 2, 32))[c(1, 3, 5)]

Note
Generate input test.csv:
Lines <- 'A,B,C
1,2,"[{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]"
3,4,"[{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]"
5,6,"[{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]"
7,8,"[{"C1":"C6.bmp","C2": "C5.bmp"}]"'
writeLines(Lines, "test.csv")

